# What am I doing wrong in this Python program using functions?

Tags: python, function

Let me preface this by saying I am a total newbie to Python programming.  Sorry to bother anyone with a possibly trivial question. But I am creating a program that calculates the user's BMI and displays their info along with their calculated BMI.  I must create a function for the following:
1. BMI calculation
2. Retrieve user's weight
3. Retrieve user's height
4. Display user's weight, height, and calculated BMI

Here is my code:
[BMI Calculator Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXel9.jpg)

These are my results:
[Code Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS9WK.jpg)

I'm supposed to show the calculated results too, but I'm doing one step at a time, making sure I can at least print the inputs first which is not happening. I'm so confused and don't know what to do to fix it. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't write the `return` statement in `methods`

Comment: Future reference, always post the code and its output in your question and not an image of the code. The editing tools have code formatting tools to help format the code for readability.

Comment: got it. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt)

your input in function do not return any value to `w`, `h`, `name` in main code.

so, function need to be

```
def get_weight():
    return int(input('message'))
```

`return` pass value to caller, now w can get value returned by `get_weight` function

```
w = get_weight()
```

Comment: and recommend you to see some basic python document. It's must be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much man. That's all it really was. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem & Solution

You are getting the user input correctly, but you need to actually `return` the user input from the function for the value to accessible outside of the function. Currently in your code you are simply getting your user input, converting it to an integer, and immediately throwing away the values by letting them be garbage collected.

To return the value from the functions, use the [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) keyword:

```
def get_weight():
    return int(input(...))

def get_height():
    return int(input(...))
```

### Improvements

Along with the solution above, there are some general improvements you can make to your code:

- Follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Put spaces between parameter, a newline at the end of the source file.
- Use newline characters, rather than extra calls to `print`, for whitespace around displayed text. For example, use:

  ```
  print('\nBMI calculator\n')
  ```

  Rather than:

  ```
  print()
  print('BMI calculator')
  print()
  ```